# firebase HTTP function termination

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it OK practice to put additional logic into a Firebase HTTPS function, after the response was sent?

I have functions where this is happening:

1. write to the Firebase DB
2. once the write is done, I send back the response (this is where `res.status(200 / 500).send()` is
   called)
3. I look up some FCM tokens in the DB and send a push message (it does not matter from a requester perspective if this is successful or not)

I understand that another pattern could be that I move step 3 to another DB trigger function to do the messaging. That would introduce some delay as I'd need to wait for that DB trigger function to fire.

My question is: is it safe to put additional logic to a HTTPS function after the
response is sent, or Firebase may start to cleanup / terminate my function already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

While your sending of FCM messages (in step 3) may frequently work, it is not reliable. There is no guarantee that the HTTP-triggered function will continue running after a response has been sent.

Precisely for this reason the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add_the_addmessage_function) says:

> HTTP functions are synchronous, so you should send a response as quickly as possible and defer work using Cloud Firestore.

So in your case, the documentation explicitly says to put the sending of the notification into a database-triggered function.

Comment: Hi puf, what an honor :) thank you very much. I'll convert step 3 to database triggers ! Thanks again.