# Why Does My Firebase HTTPS Function Go Silent When I Try to Save to Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I can write an HTTPS endpoint in Firebase that accepts POST requests. I can use it and get a response from it. I can console.log() all day long.

I log each and every step as it decides what to do with the request, BUT as soon as I try to save to Firestore, the whole endpoint goes silent. Whereas steps 1-7 used to cheerily console.log(), now step 8 sucks the whole thing into a black hole.

I thought I was doing something wrong with async/await/promises, so I replaced "Step 8" with a silly setTimeout promise. That works fine: my promise writes to console.log after 2000 milliseconds. Then I thought there was a problem with the data I was saving (since this all started when I tried to fix a warning about storing dates in Firestore). I replaced my data with {test: "Test"} - black hole again.

It seems like just the act of saving to the database creates a black hole. But only on this one endpoint. I have others that do similar things just fine.

I have been looking at this issue for days, so any help would be appreciated.

```
app.post("/webhook", async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  if(req.body.token !== functions.config().service.verification_token)
    throw new Error("Unauthorized access");

  if(req.body.type === "url_verification")
  {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('CHALLENGE_RESPONSE');
    return;
  }

  res.end("OK");

  if(DEBUG) { console.log("Received a request", req.body); }

  if(req.body.type === "event_callback")
  {
    if(DEBUG) { console.log("This request appears to be an event"); }

    if(req.body.event.type === "message")
    {
      if(DEBUG) { console.log("This event appears to concern a message"); }

      if(shouldIgnoreMessage(req.body.event))
      {
        if(DEBUG) { console.log("Actually, this event is not something we care about. We're done here."); }
        return;
      }

      if(DEBUG) { console.log("Whoa-ho! This is a message from a user! We have to deal with this."); }

      saveToFirebase(req.body).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an `await` before a promise

I also recommend removing your `res.end("OK");`, since it will end the response process.
Or moving it down to give an actual response based on if the logic in the endpoint succeeds or fails.

Try this:

```
try {    
  const saved = await saveToFirebase(req.body);
  console.log('Saved to firebase', saved)
  return res.sendStatus(200);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return res.sendStatus(500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to do this without messing with .end() since part of my requirements is to respond very quickly. The answer might end up being to fire off a message rather than doing any of this.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because moving res.end() into the .then() of the database call fixed the specific problem that I complained about. My logging messages reappeared and I got a database record. But I think ultimately the answer is going to be to not do any work after ending the response as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705401/firebase-http-function-termination and perhaps using Firebase Cloud Messaging to trigger a job.